# Angular 4 Pipe/Directive DOM manipulation

Tags: angular, dom, angular-directive, renderer, angular-pipe

I am trying to break down a paragraph into separate lines based on '.'.

Thus far, I have been able to create a pipe that does exactly that.

```
import {ElementRef, Pipe, PipeTransform, Renderer2} from "@angular/core";

    @Pipe({
        name: 'parseText'
    })
    export class ParseTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

        constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef) {}

        transform(text: string) {
            let lines: string[] = text.split('.');

            const list = this.renderer.createElement('ol');

            for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                const listItem = this.renderer.createElement('li');
                const line = this.renderer.createText(lines[i]);

                this.renderer.appendChild(listItem, line);
                this.renderer.appendChild(list, listItem);
            }

            console.log('from pipe');
            console.log(list);

            return list;
        }
    }
```

in html:

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
        {{someText | parseText}}
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Now, when I return this list, which logs as `<ol>...</ol>` in the console. However, the browser renders it as an `HTMLOListElement object`. How do I render as a html tag?

Comment: Because you're returning an object from the transform method, and this object is then transformed to a string and the displayed in the DOM. Use a component to display HTML. That's what they're for. A pipe is used to transform an input value into another value.

Comment: I thought about using a component or directive but I leaned towards a pipe. I'm gonna try a component.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. A component worked just fine. :)